# PHP delete from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array. How I can delete those values which doesn't have value in [1]? So if there's not "x", it will be deleted.

Before:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => x
        [2] => name1
        [3] => company1
        [4] => 709
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => x
        [2] => name2
        [3] => company2
        [4] => 500
    )
.
.
.
[978] => Array
    (
        [0] => 946
        [1] => 
        [2] => name946
        [3] => company946
        [4] => 0
    )

[979] => Array
    (
        [0] => 946
        [1] => x
        [2] => name946
        [3] => company946
        [4] => 0
    )

[980] => Array
    (
        [0] => 946
        [1] => 
        [2] => name946
        [3] => company946
        [4] => 0
    )
)
```

After:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => x
        [2] => name1
        [3] => company1
        [4] => 709
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => x
        [2] => name2
        [3] => company2
        [4] => 500
    )
.
.
.
[979] => Array
    (
        [0] => 946
        [1] => x
        [2] => name946
        [3] => company946
        [4] => 0
    )


)
```

Comment: Just iterate through sub-arrays and delete the subarray which does not have x

Comment: `$myArray = array_filter($myArray, function($element) { return !empty($element[1]); });`

Answer (score -1):

Just loop on your table :

```
foreach($lines AS $k => $row) {
    if($row[1] !== 'x') {
        unset($lines[$k]);
    }
}
```